# Loading csv data into Big Query via API

Tags: python, database, google-bigquery

I'm trying to upload a CSV file to a big query database, however i keep getting the following message.

```
RuntimeError: [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'kid=70943:mkey=customer_encrypt_cns/file-00000000', 'message': 'Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the error stream for more details.'}, {'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'kid=70943:mkey=customer_encrypt_cns/file-00000000', 'message': 'Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 1, but line starting at position:0 contains only 1 columns.'}]
```

The data in the csv matches the schema and as a test im only uploading 5 rows of 8columns e.g.

```
2018-02-02  x   0.1 2.4 0   0   0.88    0.4
2018-02-03  y   0.1 3   0   0   0.87    0.21
2018-02-04  z   0.1 2.8 0   0   0.86    0.21
2018-02-05  a   0.1 2.4 0   0   0.91    0.21
2018-02-06  b   0.1 1.9 0   0   1.00    0.4
```

Why does it say i only have 1 column?

Comment: This looks like a *tab* separated file instead of a comma separated file. Are you specifying the appropriate separator?

Comment: CSV is a comma delimited file. but in your data sample there are no Commas. Are you sure you are uploading a comma delimited file ?

Answer (score 2):

It says that you have 1 column because your data isn't formatted/parsed into a proper CSV file as there's no clear field delimiter. I've properly formatted the data to be tab-separated and was able to load it into BigQuery allowing me to obtain 5 rows of 8 columns.

Here is the data used:

```
2018-02-06  x   0.1 2.4 0   0   0.88    0.4
2018-02-03  y   0.1 3   0   0   0.87    0.21
2018-02-04  z   0.1 2.8 0   0   0.86    0.21
2018-02-05  a   0.1 2.4 0   0   0.91    0.21
2018-02-06  b   0.1 1.9 0   0   1.00    0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the request body ?

Looks like BigQuery cannot parse the file with the provided options. 
Regarding you file, you should specify "fieldDelimiter":"\t" option. 
You may review BigQuery API [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load) for details.

BigQuery also supports [schema auto-detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#auto-detect) for comma (,), pipe(|) and tab(\t) separated fields.